# Gibbs sampling scheme on Ozone35 data set

Tags: r, regression, bayesian

I'm attempting to run a Gibbs sampling scheme on the data set Ozone35 from the BayesVarSel package in R.

Here is the info on the data set Ozone35:

```
A data frame with 178 observations on the following 36 variables.

y Response = Daily maximum 1-hour-average ozone reading (ppm) at Upland, CA

x4 500-millibar pressure height (m) measured at Vandenberg AFB

x5 Wind speed (mph) at Los Angeles International Airport (LAX)

x6 Humidity (percentage) at LAX

x7 Temperature (Fahrenheit degrees) measured at Sandburg, CA

x8 Inversion base height (feet) at LAX

x9 Pressure gradient (mm Hg) from LAX to Daggett, CA

x10 Visibility (miles) measured at LAX

x4.x4 =x4*x4

x4.x5 =x4*x5

x4.x6 =x4*x6

x4.x7 =x4*x7

x4.x8 =x4*x8

x4.x9 =x4*x9

x4.x10 =x4*x1010 Ozone35

x5.x5 =x5*x5

x5.x6 =x5*x6

x5.x7 =x5*x7

x5.x8 =x5*x8

x5.x9 =x5*x9

x5.x10 =x5*x10

x6.x6 =x6*x6

x6.x7 =x6*x7

x6.x8 =x6*x8

x6.x9 =x6*x9

x6.x10 =x6*x10

x7.x7 =x7*x7

x7.x8 =x7*x8

x7.x9 =x7*x9

x7.x10 =x7*x10

x8.x8 =x8*x8

x8.x9 =x8*x9

x8.x10 =x8*x10

x9.x9 =x9*x9

x9.x10 =x9*x10

x10.x10 =x10*x10
```

I ran the following Gibbs sampling scheme to determine the optimal model:

```
Oz35.GibbsBvs<- GibbsBvs(formula="y~.", data=Ozone35, prior.betas="gZellner",
                     prior.models="Constant", n.iter=10000,     
init.model="null",n.burnin=100, time.test = FALSE)
```

However, I receive the error message "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" when I run the following code:

```
plotBvs(Oz35.GibbsBvs, option="conditional")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running this in Rstudio? Sometimes you need to make the plot window larger to accommodate the graph.

Comment: Thanks. No issues when I ran it in R.